# How to solve the following integral that gives the solution of the wave equation bi dimensional.

Tags: wave-equation

I ask to solve the following PDE:

$$u_{tt}-\triangle u=0$$
$$u(x,y,0)=x$$
$$u_t(x,y,0)=0$$

I know that the general solution to this equation is

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3\pi t^2}\int_{B(x,t)}\displaystyle \frac{tg(y)+t^2h(y)+tDg(y)\cdot(y-x)}{(t^2-|y-x|^2)^{1/2}}$$

for $t>0$. This is given from the Evans.

Then I replace the values to get

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3\pi t^2}\int_{B(x,t)}\displaystyle\frac{ty_1+t(1,0)\cdot(y-x)}{(t^2-|x-y|^2)^{1/2}}dy$$

taken $y=(y_1,y_2)$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)$

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3\pi t^2}\int_{B(x,t)}\displaystyle\frac{2ty_1-tx_1}{(t^2-|x-y|^2)^{1/2}}dy$$

splitting this equation in two equations

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle\frac{4}{3\pi t}\int_{B(x,t)}\displaystyle\frac{y_1}{(t^2-|x-y|^2)^{1/2}}dy-\displaystyle\frac{2x_1}{3\pi t}\int_{B(x,t)}\displaystyle\frac{1}{(t^2-|x-y|^2)^{1/2}}dy$$

I know how to solve the second equation using spherical coordinates, but how can I solve the first one? Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to go through all that work. Since the initial condition depends only on $x$, the same will be true of the solution. This leads to a one-dimensional wave equation, and the solution is
$$
u(x,y)=x.
$$